# Centering a group of equations and text both which is used in \begin{align*}.....\end{align*}

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

Say I am trying to center a group of equations, written in separate lines, with equality sign aligned one below another, which are defined by: `$f(r)+1=g(r^2)+1=O(r)$ as $r\to 1$` by first using the following sequence of commands for centering:

```
\begin{align*}

& f(r)+1 \\
&=g(r^2)+2 \\
&=O(r)\\

\end{align*}
```

followed by as `$r\to 1$`. But this put  `$r\to 1$` in a different line, not in the same line with O(r). I want the last line to be written as: `$O(r)$ as $r\to 1$`, centered in the middle of the page. How can I achieve this ? Thank you!

Comment: You can use `O(r) \text{ as } r\to 1` as the final entry (and you don't want `\\ ` after the last row).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
f(r)+1  &=g(r^2)+2 \\
        &=O(r) \qquad \text{as } r\to 1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```